# Understanding one condition in Pontryagin Maximum Principle

Tags: optimal-control

This is a public course note about the optimal control problem.

[https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/control.course.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eevans/control.course.pdf)

There is one condition that I do not get. Is there any intuition that we need "the mapping is constant"? And how does that be derived? It seems very strong. I usually do not see that in the textbook.

[image: Problem]

[image: Theorem]

Comment: This is true in general for optimal control problems where the Hamiltonian is *autonomous*, i.e. doesn't depend explicitly on $t$.  I don't have a digital reference on hand, but "autonomous" is the keyword to search for.